# How to set datetimepicker value to only date in (.NET)

Tags: c#, .net

I have DateTimePicker on my form and I set a value to the custom format property to **"dd/MM/yyyy"** ant when I run this code:

`MessageBox.Show(dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString());`

I get this value : "3/26/2010 1:26 PM".

How I can remove the time part from value.

I know we can use this method

```
dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString();
```

but I want to set the value property to this format **"dd/MM/yyyy"** so the output will be like this **"26/3/2010"**, because I want to store the value in my DB (SQL)

How I can do that?

Comment: If you want to store the date-part of your `System.DateTime` in your DB, why do you take a formatted string into the DB? ... rather use `dateTimePicker1.Value.Date` and then store this in your column (which might be dateTime or date - whatever your DB allows)

Answer (score 17):

Use `dateTimePicker1.Value.Date` to get the Date part of this DateTime value.

Do notice though, if you mean to parse into strings, that using `dateTimePicker1.Value.Date.ToString` will result with the "26/03/2010 00:00:00" string, while using something like `MyString = CStr(dateTimePicker1.Value.Date)` will result in MyString being "26/03/2010".

Answer (score 5):

If you have string as datatype in database:

```
  dateTimePicker1.Value.Date.ToString("d");
```

If datatype is DateTime:

```
  dateTimePicker1.Value.Date;
```

Both will return date in dd/mm/yyyy format without time.

Comment: perhaps you could explain how this answers the OPs question? Also - what happens if a user has a different culture on their machine?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how it answers the question would significantly improve its long-term value. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Comment: @JasonMc92 Thanks,I am new to stackoverflow. I added some explanation.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you initialized the DateTimePicker with the current date and time:

```
dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now;
```

Instead, initialize it with the current date:

```
dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Today;
```

What happens is as follows:

- If the user selects a date, then the `DateTimePicker.Value` property will always return a date with no time of day component, and `DateTime.Kind` set to `Unspecified`.
- If the user doesn't select a date, then the `DateTimePicker.Value` property will return the value used to initialize the `DateTimePicker.Value` property.  If you initialize it with `DateTime.Now`, it will have a time of day component, and `DateTime.Kind` will be set to `Local`.

Answer (score 1):

just `MessageBox.Show(dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));`

Comment: I want to do this:

datetimepicker.value = 26/03/2010

Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: datetimepicker.Value = new DateTime(2010, 3, 26); or 
datetimepicker.Value = Convert.ToDateTime("26/03/2010");

Comment: Use ParseExact like below. Substitute the date string in the first parameter with whatever string variable you have in your program. 
DateTime dtResult = DateTime.ParseExact("26/03/2010", "d/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

See here for more info http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx

Comment: this is culture-dependent and not considered best practice, as this format is covered by the method `.ToShortDateString()`

Answer (score 0):

```cs
dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")
```

This should work

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please use the availible formatting options in your question and answers. Give it a try and [edit] your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can set DateTimePicker "Format" to "Short" in Properties window (under Appearance)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30396434)